# Logging extra field in python JSON logs

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to log an additional json property into my info logs, so i can reach it over Elastic.

here it is how it looks like:

```
log.info("message with object", {'simple_obj': json.dumps(str(body_dict['message_details'])).replace('"',"'")})
```

is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I use `json_logging` to print additional properties.

```
import sys
import logging
import json_logging

json_logging.init_non_web(enable_json=True)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

logger.info("no extra props")

print("\n")

extra_props = {'props': { "name": 'test'}}
logger.info("extra props", extra=extra_props)
```

**Output**:

```
{"written_at": "2022-12-14T22:17:13.530Z", "written_ts": 1671056233530158000, "msg": "no extra props", "type": "log", "logger": "__main__", "thread": "MainThread", "level": "INFO", "module": "test", "line_no": 10}


{"written_at": "2022-12-14T22:17:13.530Z", "written_ts": 1671056233530459000, "msg": "extra props", "type": "log", "logger": "__main__", "thread": "MainThread", "level": "INFO", "module": "test", "line_no": 15, "name": "test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library [python-json-logger](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger)

```
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

logger = logging.getLogger()

logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
```

Comment: I already have the formatter set and the handler.
The formatter is a custom JSON structure, but how to add this property into it?

Comment: You have example there: https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger#adding-custom-object-serialization

Comment: doesnt helped me at all, sorry!

I want to add it to my current handler, just to add additional property to my log.

I do not want to reformat the whole logging!!!

Comment: And the second import is corrupted!!!